# dynamic image crop in php

Tags: php

hi i am using smart resizer (http://shiftingpixel.com/2008/03/03/smart-image-resizer/).
when i am giving path of files which exist on my server .this script gives me proper result.
but i path of another server , in this case this script is not giving proper result.

For using this script i have to pass this value in img src like following

but i want to use this as

how can i do this.

Answer (score 1):

I've just looked quickly into the script and saw that it is **not possible** to resize remote files ;-).
So you either have to adapt the script to be able to resize remote files (which means that it has to be stored locally and then be resized) or you use another script ;-).

Comment: i have modified the script. Now I ma getting good result from this on first time .But when cache is created then it starts problem.